# Convert excel-file to pdf-file

Tags: java, excel, pdf, openpyxl

I have used openpyxl to autogenerate 154 excel files. Everything worked like a charm!

Now I need to convert the excel-files into pdf-files. 
Can this be done automatically or do I need to do it manually?

Note: It is important that I have the option to define margins and horizontal orientation. A solution in python in preferred. I'm using OS X or Ubuntu.

Comment: Which operating system? You can probably automate Excel on windows to print the document to a PDF.

Comment: Using OS X or Ubuntu. Windows is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: The probably using LibreOffice/OpenOffice and [uno](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Printing_Spreadsheet_Documents)?

Never done it but seems doable.

Comment: Run LibreOffice in headless mode and get it to do it but basically you should be using a library to generate the PDFs directly.

Comment: Thank you lazy1 for your advise.  If you post an answer then I'll be able to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using a combination of Java, [UNO, and OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/udk/). Thank you lazy1 for your advise.

For any interested peers: My implementation can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/Vingtoft/UNO-excel-to-pdf-converter)